# Pipe command with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a script which run this command successfully. I am using this command in another script which gives me error on this line (`.md5: Permission denied`).

I am running the previous script with sudo.

```
for i in ${NAME}*
do
    sudo md5sum $i | sed -e "s/$i/${NAME}/" > ${NAME}.md5${i/#${NAME}/}
done
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you want to redirect output as root. It doesn't matter that you executed the command with `sudo`, because redirection is not part of the execution, so it's not performed by the executing user of the command, but by your current user.

The common trick is to use `tee`:

```
for i in "${NAME}"*
do
    sudo md5sum "$i" | sed -e "s/$i/${NAME}/" | sudo tee "${NAME}.md5${i/#${NAME}/}"
done
```

Note: `tee` outputs in two directions: the specified file and stdout. If you want to suppress the output on stdout, redirect it to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I used the above command getting an error                                                 (( sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression ))

Comment: @Sherry that looks like a completely unrelated issue. It can happen for example if the value of `$i` is empty. Add an `echo "i=$i"` line before the `md5sum ...` line, and make sure the value is correct

Comment: So, when you say "I dropped the `sudo` from `md5sum`, as probably you don't need it." are you assuming the OP has read access to the file(s) being processed?

Comment: @MarkStewart indeed, I made that assumption. It's probably simpler if I don't make that assumption. I updated the answer, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

You take the output of `sudo md5sum $i` and pipe it to a sed which is not running as root. sudo doesn't even know this sed exists.

But that's not the problem, because the sed does not need root permissions. The problem is `> ${NAME}...`. This redirects the output of sed to the file with this name. But the redirection is actually executed by your shell which is running as your user. And because `>` is a shell built-in operator, you can not prefix it with sudo.

The simple solution is to use `tee`. `tee` is a program (so you can run it with sudo) which writes it's input to the standard output and also to a file (like a T-Pipe, hence the name).
So you can just:

```
for i in ${NAME}*
do
    md5sum $i | sed -e "s/$i/${NAME}/" | sudo tee ${NAME}.md5${i/#${NAME}/}
done
```

Note this will also dump all hashes to your standard output.