# Can't create environment file with aws secretsmanager command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, secretsmanager

I am trying to run the following command on an EC2 instance I manage.

```
sudo aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "KingsKidzApplication-env" --region "ap-southeast-2" | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\\\"\(.value|tostring)\\\"\")|.[]" > "/srv/kingskidz/.env"
```

However I get the message `-bash: /srv/kingskidz/.env: Permission denied`

It does not create the .env file. What am I doing wrong here? I have sudo writes for the server. I have given the ec2 AMI role the full permission for secret manager.

[image]

Comment: It is saying you don't have permission to the `/srv/kingskidz/.env` file. It has nothing to do with AWS IAM permissions/roles.

Comment: yes, but why? I am using sudo.

Comment: You have multiple commands piped into each other. Only the first of those commands is running as root. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292676/pipe-command-with-sudo